# IDE thinks ndarray (n>1) that is operated on by a float (int, etc.) is a float int, etc.)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, pycharm

Say

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
b = a - 1
b[2, 1] = 3
```

Pycharm marks yellow on `b[2]` and complains:

```
Class 'int' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances
```

On the other hand, this would be fine:

```
a = np.arange(15)
b = a - 1
b[2] = 3
```

This is really stupid and annoying. How to get rid of it?

Comment: oh wow. Are you on the latest version of PyCharm? I find it unbelievable that this has slipped by, unless this was a recent addition and only now people are starting to notice...

Comment: Edited. Seems only has problem for numpy ndarray with n>1.